# WCF Service webHttpBinding Anonymous Authentication

Tags: wcf, iis

I have a situation where by I have un ticked the anonymous authentication in IIS, so the designers and clients are able to see the work but no one else.  I need to get the WCF Service to work under these conditions but I am not sure how.

Does anyone have any idea what I would need to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can attach the credential to the URL as querystring. your WCF services( in message inspector ) can check it for authentication purposes. You might also want to enable https.